# How to copy all the files created on a specific date from one bucket to another in GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell

How can we copy all the files created on the specified date from one directory to another in GCS.

I have an archive folder from which I need to copy all the files that were created on a specified date(e.g. 20 August 2022) to another directory. We can do this by providing the list of filenames in a file and providing it as input to the *gsutil cp* command however I am having 500+ files and don't have the names of all of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Data transfer service to copy data from one GCS to another one.

On the second step, select advanced filters and pick the absolute time range
[image]

It should meet your expectation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this command :

```
gsutil ls -l gs://{SOURCE_BUCKET}/ | grep 2022-08-20 | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev | gsutil -m cp -I gs://{DESTINATION_BUCKET}/
```